# SublimeREPL not loading my conda installation when using IPython

Tags: python, autocomplete, ipython, sublimetext3, conda

I installed sublime Text 3 here at work, with packages like `Python-Autocompletion`, `SublimeJedi` or `sublimeREPL`.

When I initialise Python through sublimeREPL (`Tools > SublimeREPL > Python > Python`) I see the standard Python header:

```
Python 2.7.10 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 28 2015, 17:04:42) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
```

And everything seems to work fine, including autocompletion.

However, when I run IPython (`Tools > SublimeREPL > Python > IPython`), I just get:

```
IPython Console 3.1.0

In [1]:
```

Instead of the expected:

```
Python 2.7.10 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 28 2015, 17:04:42)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
```

Somehow, is not finding the python installation and just launching the console. I can still code in there but autocompletion won't work at all.

I though I have found a solution by updating my IPython installation, but is not the case. Basically, Sublime is still not initializing my IPython installation.

I read here [SublimeREPL error](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/417) that a similar problem was thought to be related to `IPython 3.1.0` and the solution was to downgrade IPython.

I am sure there has to be a more, let's say "efficient" or elegant solution than downgrading (??). If not, what is a save way to downgrade IPython?

Anyway, at this stage I have tried different Sublime settings and packages and nothing seems to work! Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Is there a reason you deleted your answer?

Comment: @MattDMo: yes, there was a reason. It seemed to work, but it was not the case. When I load IPython in sublime, wherever Sublime is initialised from, IPython "lands" in `/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS`. In other words, When I type `pwd` in the IPython console in Sublime this is the result. I am not an expert in Sublime, so I am not sure whether this is expected or not. Anyway, as soon as you type any command not related with `python` (e.g. `cd`, `ls`, `pwd`) autocompletion and some other features stop working. To summarise, sublime is not finding my IPython installation.

Comment: In any case, I followed the same installation process in my personal, old (10.6.9) mac at home, where I have Python 2.7.6 and IPython 2.0.0  (the question above, as you'll see, refers to my work laptop, where I have Python 2.7.10 and IPython 3.2).  I installed Sublime Text 2 and SublimeREPL and everything works perfectly, which seems to confirm that the lack of functionality is related to the IPython 3. versions.